# SQL search for values in a field with text datatype regardless of casing

Tags: sql-server, select, text, lowercase

I am trying to get all values for a particular search regardless of casing. On our SQL Server database case sensitivity is turned on and I don't want to have to change this if possible.

If I do a SELECT statement that includes the LOWER() function as follows

```
SELECT COUNT(blogpostId) as blogpostcount
FROM blogposts
WHERE stateId = '1'
AND blogId = '20'
AND LOWER(blogpostContent) LIKE '%test%'
```

it throws and error to say

> Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of lower function.

The data type for the `blogpostContent` column is `text`. If I change this to `nvarchar` this works however `nvarchar` only allows a maximum of 255 chars and I need a lot more than this.

Is there anyway to check for results in the text field regardless of casing??

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx says max length for nvarchar is 2^31-1 (and in almost every DBMS varchars can be thousands of chars long).

Comment: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` allows **up to 2 GB** of text!! (available in SQL Server 2005 and newer) That's Tolstoj's *War and Peace* - several times over! Isn't that enough??? `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are deprecated as of SQL Server 2005 and should not be used - also because exactly this problem: they don't support many of the string functions...

Comment: nvarchar should allow 4000 characters, not 255. For SQL Server 2005+, you can use nvarchar(max).

Comment: Seems I may have been missinformed about how many characters a nvarchar allows. I was always told to use text if it was over 255. woops

Comment: Wasn't this originally due to an 8k page size?  I assume large columns such as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` can take up multiple pages without hurting performance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could explicity force it to use a CASE INSENSITIVE collation like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(blogpostId) as blogpostcount  
FROM blogposts  
WHERE stateId='1'  
AND blogId = '20'  
AND blogpostContent LIKE '%test%'  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Comment: This works which saves me changing the design of the table. Genius!